# Limitar del 1 al 30 en un edit ( xsl )

Tags: java, xsl, xslt

Tengo un edit en XSL y solo quiero que se pueda escribir del 1 al 30 pero no consigo como hacerlo.

He intentando con el min y el max pero veo que no se puede.

Alguna ayuda?

Gracias de antemano.

```
                    <widget size="45%,55%" bgvisible="false" >
                        <edit id="siguienteRonda" size="90%,20" class="editUpper" numeric="True" maxlength="2" label="{//PopShow/target/nextRound}"/>
                    </widget>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el problema, ¿puedes subir el código que tienes?

Comment: @nachfren Ya está subido, lo que quiero es que la persona que escriba un número en ese edit que solo pueda escribir un numero que este entre el 1 y el 30.